# Search for string within a List with Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, search, nested

-- EDIT:

Okay thanks to you guys, and especially randomir I adjusted the loop as follows:

```
while buy_active > 0 or balance_available > 0 or i <= 0:
        print('Selling {0} {1} for {2:.8f} {3}. Volume: {4} It {5}'.format(balance_available, currency, coinprice_sell, trade, coinvolume, i))
        api.selllimit(market, balance_available, coinprice_sell)

        open_order = api.getopenorders(market)
        buy_active = len(list(filter(partial(eq, "LIMIT_BUY"),
                                map(itemgetter("OrderType"), open_order)))) > 0

        coinbalance = api.getbalance(currency)
        balance_available = coinbalance['Available']  # You still have some coins available
        coinsummary = api.getmarketsummary(market)
        coinprice = coinsummary[0]['Last']
        coinvolume = coinsummary[0]['Volume'] * coinprice
        i += 1
else:
        print('No open Buy order or remaining quantity')
```

Now this codes runs almost all the time perfectly but once in a while I receive an error (which I do not know how to replicate, since it probably depends on what the API transmits to the program.

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 76, in <module>
    while buy_active > 0 or balance_available > 0 or i <= 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So I interpret the error that sometimes the variable buy_active has no type and hence cannot be interpreted with ">". However, I do not see how this can happen. It probably has something to do with the len(list(filter(... approach. I also tried to define buy_active = 1 so it enters the loop at least once. But this does not solve the problem. Hence I guess this operator sometimes deliveres a NoneType character.

Does anybody has a suggestion what the problem could be?

Best
SaltyJ

---

Original:

I just started programming in python 2.7 (for this particular code I would like to stay on 2.7) where I encountered a problem. Since I am very new to programming, I cannot figure out how to solve my problem. I hope you can help.

I want to handle some input from an API about my open orders at an online exchange.

Over the API I receive a list with nested dictionnaries. One Example (for 2 orders is below).

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "09aa5bb6-8232-41aa-9b78-a5a1093e0211",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_SELL",
            "Quantity" : 5.00000000,
            "QuantityRemaining" : 5.00000000,
            "Limit" : 2.00000000,
            "CommissionPaid" : 0.00000000,
            "Price" : 0.00000000,
            "PricePerUnit" : null,
            "Opened" : "2014-07-09T03:55:48.77",
            "Closed" : null,
            "CancelInitiated" : false,
            "ImmediateOrCancel" : false,
            "IsConditional" : false,
            "Condition" : null,
            "ConditionTarget" : null
        }, {
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "8925d746-bc9f-4684-b1aa-e507467aaa99",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_BUY",
            "Quantity" : 100000.00000000,
            "QuantityRemaining" : 100000.00000000,
            "Limit" : 0.00000001,
            "CommissionPaid" : 0.00000000,
            "Price" : 0.00000000,
            "PricePerUnit" : null,
            "Opened" : "2014-07-09T03:55:48.583",
            "Closed" : null,
            "CancelInitiated" : false,
            "ImmediateOrCancel" : false,
            "IsConditional" : false,
            "Condition" : null,
            "ConditionTarget" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

The API produces a list with one dictionnary for every open order.

Now I want to basically make my code go through all dic. looking for the string "LIMIT_BUY".

My current code does this for up to 2 orders. But it is probably highly inefficient and also cannot cope with orders > 2:

At the end of the loop the buy_active variable should  be "1" if there is any buy order or 0 if there is no order or only selling orders.

```
if len(open_order) == 2:
            order_type_1 = open_order[0]['OrderType']
            order_type_2 = open_order[1]['OrderType']
            if order_type_1 == 'LIMIT_BUY' or order_type_2 == 'LIMIT_BUY':
                buy_active = 1
            else:
                buy_active = 0

        elif len(open_order) == 1:
            order_type_1 = open_order[0]['OrderType']
            if order_type_1 == 'LIMIT_BUY':
                buy_active = 1
            else:
                buy_active = 0
        else:
            buy_active = 0
```

What I would like is a most efficient (in terms of time) code to look through the list with any number of entries.

Can somebody help me?:)

Thanks alot! I just started coding 4 days ago, so please be nice :)

Best
SaltyJ

Comment: `if len(open_order) == 2:` can be changed to `if len(open_order)` to cover all dictionaries. 

further, you can use a `loop` to go over every dictionary and store the result in a `list`

Answer (score 0):

This would be the **imperative programming** approach, simply looping over values in `open_order` list:

```
buy_active = False
for order in open_order:
    if order.get("OrderType") == "LIMIT_BUY":
        buy_active = True
        break
```

We use a [`for` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) to iterate over items in the list, and then we [safely inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) each item (which is a dictionary) - to see if it contains a key `OrderType`, and if does, is it equal to `LIMIT_BUY`. When we find the first such item, we set `buy_active` to `True`, and abort any further processing (we know there is at least one item, so no point in looping over other items).

And this would be the **functional programming** approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter, eq
from functools import partial

buy_active = len(filter(partial(eq, "LIMIT_BUY"),
                        map(itemgetter("OrderType"), open_order))) > 0
```

The boolean variable `buy_active` will be `True` if at least one `LIMIT_BUY` was found as a value for `OrderType`, same as in previous approach.

Here we use the built-in function called [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to evaluate function `itemgetter("OrderType")` over each item in `open_order` collection of dictionaries. The [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) will extract `"OrderType"` from each dictionary, and the result of the mapping will be a list of all `OrderType`s, like this: `["LIMIT_SELL", "LIMIT_BUY", ...]`.

We now apply [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) on that list, and with [partially](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) applied [`eq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.eq) operator we check if any of the items is equal to `"LIMIT_BUY"`. That filters-out all that are not, producing a list: `["LIMIT_BUY", ...]`.

After that, we simply check the length of the list, and declare `buy_active` is `True` if the list is not empty.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly! Thank you, I learned alot following your logic!

Comment: I just switched the code to python 3.6 (from 2.7) and now I receive an error code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 75, in <module>
    map(itemgetter("OrderType"), open_order))) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()

Comment: That's because in Python 3, `filter`, `map`, etc. return an iterator, instead of list. You can expand it to a list with `list`, like this: `list(filter(...))`.

Comment: thank you! I am sorry for being so incompetent but now the code "buy_active = len(list(filter(partial(eq, "LIMIT_BUY"))," returns the following error : buy_active = len(list(filter(partial(eq, "LIMIT_BUY")),
TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1 .

Comment: Try it like this: `buy_active = len(list(filter(partial(eq, "LIMIT_BUY"), map(itemgetter("OrderType"), open_order)))) > 0`

Comment: Thank you again !:) Do you have an idea how to deal with my current issue (seen in the edit of the question)

Comment: @SaltyJ, please don't keep adding new questions to an existing question. Rather, create a new one. Please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what you should do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @SaltyJ, and to answer your follow-up question: at some point your `buy_active` or `balance_available` variable is set to `None`. You can compare `None` with integers. Check when is this done by adding a few debugging `print` statements in your loop: `print(buy_active, balance_available)`.

Comment: @SaltyJ, please consider [upvoting helpful answers and closing the question by accepting one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful art of coding!

You've encountered your first repetitive task so it seems. This might be the time to look into [for-loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or [while-loops](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while). They allow you to repeat tasks.

For example, though greatly simplified:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
# Your way:
print mylist[0]
print mylist[1]
print mylist[2]
# This works, but gets tedious if your list grows.

# This is way more concise:
for i in mylist:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function and list comprehension (to filter the list).
The list comprehension, creates a new list of True values, when  "OrderType" equals "LIMIT_SELL".

```
import json
data = json.loads("""{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "09aa5bb6-8232-41aa-9b78-a5a1093e0211",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_SELL",
            ....
""")

buy_active = any([True for item in data['result'] if item['OrderType'] == 'LIMIT_BUY' ])
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the approach of Randomir. Do you think the code you provided is more efficient in computing time?

Comment: It's just a one-liner :) As long as you don't have millions of orders it doesn't matter much in terms of speed.